# making requests to localhost from inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, urllib2

I have an application runing on my localhost at port 8080. I have some python code that consumes that service. The code runs fine on my base system but as soon as I put it inside a docker container I get `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>`.  I have another application that exposes an api at port 6543. Same problem.

I assume I need to tell docker that it's allowed to consume certain localhost ports. How do I do that?

Here are some more specific details:

I can execute this line of code just fine on my base system:

```
urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(dData))
```

but when I try to do it from inside a docker container then I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

I've tried adding permissions to docker.sock

```
ls -l /var/run/docker.sock      
=> srw-rw-rwx 1 root docker 0 Feb 17 11:09 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/4720042 Check this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your python container with argument `-net host`,it will share address and port with host,so it can access progress which is running on host.

Refer to my another answer： https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069763/5465023

Comment: How would I do this for the services defined in a docker-compose?

Comment: Did you find the soultion to the services defined in a docker-compose ?