# Access to localhost from a locally deployed Cloud Run container (through VS Code)

Tags: google-cloud-run, cloud-run-emulator

I am running a Cloud Run service on the Cloud Run emulator through VS Code.
At some point, I need to access to data stored on a Firebase Storage local emulator (say `localhost:9199`). However, my Python code on Cloud Run is facing this issue:

```
<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6d392af2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Some investigations led me thinking that because Cloud Run emulator is running a virtual machine, it does not know about `localhost:9199`.

Referring to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432562/making-requests-to-localhost-from-inside-docker-container), is it possible to add `-net host` option to the docker internally used by Cloud Run? If not, any idea to solve this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent/#tracing--apm)
 help to solve your issue?

Comment: Well not really. Because, I don't have direct access to Docker via the VS Code Cloud Run emulator. There is just a `launch.json` file that can be used to configure the virtual Cloud Run instance (example, specifying to use docker for building). But I couldn't find a doc specifying how to add options to `docker run`. Otherwise, I would be able to try the `-net host` option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turned out to be simpler than I thought, but if it can save to someone a few hours, here is how I solved the issue:

I simply replaced `localhost` with `host.docker.internal` in the code running from within the docker container, and that was it. Credits go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/15203755), where you will find more details based on your system config.